# Interrupting a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to gracefully shutdown the threads. I seen many codes on internet and have query here.
I think there are two approaches to shutdown.

1. use boolean flag. Once flag chnages we can break the code there in run method.
2. use of interrupt method.

My question why it is avoided to use boolean flag to gracefully shutdown the threads, When I ran sample program it went well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `boolean` flag, however:

- you need to remember about synchronization/visibility (at least put `volatile` on the flag)
- why adding an extra flag when one is already implemented (`interrupted`)?
- Other libraries/containers might try to interrupt your thread (after all, they don't know about your flag!) so you still need to support `InterruptedException` and/or `isInterrupted()` flag
- interrupting a thread can also interrupt I/O calls and `Thread.sleep()`. Your custom flag can't